# Is there a way to reenable a disabled link for a file I replaced in SharePoint?

Tags: links

I use SharePoint Publisher in my organization, I had to replace an Excel file that I shared (get link) with ~300 ppl. 
When I replaced the file, I wasn't aware that the link would change, and now when people try to open that file, they get the message: "This link has been removed".
I can't send a new communication to everyone saying that the link is broken. 
Is there a way to recover that disabled link? 
I appreciate your help with this, it's very important.
Thanks!

Comment: here , replaced means whether you uploaded the same file again or removed the existing file and added a new file with different file name?

Comment: Because if you remember the file name and keep the same file name for the new file you're uploading to the Library , then it  will have the same link as you shared with the users,